# Haskell pattern matching - Non-exhaustive pattern - but why?

Tags: haskell, exception, pattern-matching

I'm trying to create a run-length encoding function in Haskell.
I know there are lot's of examples out there, I'm not really looking for a solution but more for an explanation why mine doesn't work.

```hs
rle [] s acc = acc
rle (x:xs) s acc = rle xs s ((x, count x s) : acc)

count x = length . filter (x==)
```

For some reason Haskell isn't able to pattern match this.
e.g. `rle "abcd" "aaa" []` should return `[('a',3),('b',0),...]` but always causes a Non-exhaustive patterns Exception.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Is that how you defined it in `ghci`? If you write multi-line functions, you should surround these with `:{` and `:}`. Note however that here you will *not* generate a run length encoding.

Comment: Ah thanks, I see now why it didn't work. Thanks also for the tip with :{ :}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you defined this in `ghci`. If you write functions that span multiple lines, you should surround these by `:{` and `:}`. If you do *not* do that, you define two functions `rle`. The second one will be more locally scoped, hence if you later call `rle`, it will pick that one.

For example:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/kommusoft/.ghci
Prelude> :{
Prelude| rle [] s acc = acc
Prelude| rle (x:xs) s acc = rle xs s ((x, count x s) : acc)
Prelude| 
Prelude| count x = length . filter (x==)
Prelude| :}
Prelude> rle "abcd" "aaa" []
[('d',0),('c',0),('b',0),('a',3)]
```

Working with `count` will however *not* work here, since your `rle` each time makes one step in the list. Furthermore you here do *not* need to use an accumulator.